# ¿Bucle for y condicional?cual es el error?

Tags: python-3.x

Create one conditional to find whether “false” is in string str1. If so, assign variable output the string “False. You aren’t you?”. Check to see if “true” is in string str1 and if it is then assign “True! You are you!” to the variable output. If neither are in str1, assign “Neither true nor false!” to output.

```
  str1 = "Today you are you! That is truer than true ! There is no one alive who is you-er than you!"
  splitin=str1.split(" ")


for i in splitin:
    if i=="false":
        output="False. You aren’t you?"


    elif i== "true":
        output="True! You are you!" 


    else:
       output="Neither true nor false!"

print(output)
```

deberia imprimir “True! You are you!” pero imprime “Neither true nor false!” no entiendo que estoy haciendo mal es como si no aplicara el condicional elif?

Comment: Debes poner el texto en castellano, no todo el mundo habla inglés, por favor edita la pregunta para cambiarlo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te está devolviendo eso porque la última palabra del bucle es you. Has partido la cadena por los espacios y luego has hecho un bucle. Cuando ha terminado le has dicho que imprima output, es decir, el último valor que ha adquirido (con la última palabra).
Si quieres entender mejor lo que ha pasado, mete el print dentro del bucle así y verás que te imprime cosas diferentes según la palabra en la que está:

```
str1 = "Today you are you! That is truer than true ! There is no one alive who is you-er than you!"
splitin = str1.split(" ")

for i in splitin:
    if i == "false":
        output = "False. You aren’t you?"
    elif i == "true":
        output = "True! You are you!"
    else:
        output = "Neither true nor false!"

    print(output)
```

La salida será:

```
Neither true nor false!
Neither true nor false!
Neither true nor false!
Neither true nor false!
Neither true nor false!
Neither true nor false!
Neither true nor false!
Neither true nor false!
True! You are you! # Esta corresponde a la palabra true de la cadena.
Neither true nor false!
Neither true nor false!
Neither true nor false!
Neither true nor false!
Neither true nor false!
Neither true nor false!
Neither true nor false!
Neither true nor false!
Neither true nor false!
Neither true nor false!
Neither true nor false!
```

De todas formas no necesitas hacer el `split()` e ir analizando uno a uno. Para saber si una cadena está contenida en otra puedes usar `in` así:

```
str1 = "Today you are you! That is truer than true ! There is no one alive who is you-er than you!"

if "false" in str1:
    output = "False. You aren’t you?"
elif "true" in str1:
    output = "True! You are you!"
else:
    output = "Neither true nor false!"

print(output)
```

Comment: Gracias!! soy nueva en esto!!

Answer (score 0):

Como menciona Adrián Sanz Wallace, el problema es que imprimes la variable output luego de finalizar el bucle, por lo que esta tendra la ultima palabra de todo el string.

Si necesitas resolver el problema con el bucle podrias hacer algo asi

```
str1 = "Today you are you! That is truer than true ! There is no one alive who is you-er than you!"
splitin=str1.split(" ")

ct = 0
cf = 0

for i in splitin:
    if i=="false":
        cf = cf + 1

    elif i=="true":
        ct = ct + 1

if cf > 0:
  output="False. You aren’t you?"
elif ct > 0:
  output="True! You are you!" 
else:
  output="Neither true nor false!"

print(output)
```

Lo que se hace es declarar un contador para cada true y false, y cuentas las veces que existe en el string cada una, y en base a ese contador presentas el mensaje.